# Polly (twitter client) problem authorization

Tags: networking, settings, client, twitter, hotot

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Polly 0.93.5. 
Internet connection (l2tp) is established. No proxy.

I can't add the twitter account. In the window "Add new account" written:

```
Twitter did not authorize the request. Please try again
```

Restart request - no result.

In "Hotot" client - show message:

```
2012-11-7 0:33:0Oops, a network error occured
Network error! Please try later.
Can not get token from the server.
```

Special settings network or what?

Answer (score 0):

I report your problem to the Polly developer via the official [Polly Twitter Account (@PollyClient)](https://twitter.com/PollyClient) and he answers this :

> Problem in different clients suggest an issue on Twitter's side. I
>   suggest you just wait

Here is the tweet: https://twitter.com/PollyClient/status/279733286060843008